# how to set the multiple of image src from List<> on different imageView?

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist

I stored the image url from the firestore into the `ArrayList`, and I was successful to store all the image url into the `ArrayList`. After that, I tried to take it out by `for loop`, and inside loop it will be always looping the image url, and how I can get the looping image url value and put it on different imageView?

**The below is my code:**

```
private List<String>imgUrl= new ArrayList<>();
private ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3,imageview4,imageview5;


if(imgUrl!= null){  // size : 5
        for(int i= 0; i<imgUrl.size(); i ++){ //loop 
            //how I can loop the imageUrl here into different ImageView?
        }
    }
```

Comment: place ImageViews into the ArrayList too, and you can loop them same way

Comment: ```if(imgUrl!= null){  // size : 5
        for(int i= 0; i<imgUrl.size(); i ++){ //loop 
            String url = imgUrl.get(i);
        }
    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom xml layout file too if you want. This will be easier if you want to add descriptions below your image.
For the below example, i'm using Glide to set the image

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parentActivity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View newView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.many_image_views, null);

    if(newView != null){

        ImageView anImageView = newView.findViewById(R.id.anImageView);

        for(int i = 0; i < imgUrl.size(); i++){
            GlideApp.with(this)
                    .asBitmap().format(PREFER_RGB_565)
                    .load(imgUrl.get(i))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_image)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_not_found)
                    .into(anImageView);

            container.addView(newView);
        }
    }
}
```

many_image_views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/anImageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of ImageViews

```
private List<String> imgUrl= new ArrayList<>();
private ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3,imageview4,imageview5;

private ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[]{imageview1, imageview2, imageview3,imageview4,imageview5};

if(imgUrl!= null){  // size : 5
    for(int i= 0; i<imgUrl.size(); i ++){ //loop
        //how I can loop the imageUrl here into different ImageView?
        Picasso.get().load(imgUrl.get(i)).into(imageViewArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList();
images.add(imageview1);
images.add(imageview2);
images.add(imageview3);
images.add(imageview4);
images.add(imageview5);

int cnt = 0;
for (String url : imgUrl) {
    cnt++;
    ImageView img = images.get(cnt);

}
```

Comment: Bro, thanks you have given me some idea, but it seens like the array cannot using put(), it use add()

Comment: Upps! Sorry. Too much in my head right now; I mixed it. Editing my answer.

Comment: Haha its okay, you given me idea from the arraylist to add all my imageview, but the for loop there is not working, please check your `url` in for each loop is not using as you assign it with the `imgUrl` lol. Anyway thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are having these ImageViews into your XML, You can use Picasso or something to load URL into images, you can do something like this -

> You need to take the reference to all these images first.

```
 private List<String> imgUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3, imageview4, imageview5;

    imageViews.add(imageview1);
    imageViews.add(imageview2);
    imageViews.add(imageview3);
    imageViews.add(imageview4);
    imageViews.add(imageview5);

    if (imgUrl != null) {  
        for(int i=0;i<imgUrl.size();i++){
            Picasso.get().load(imgUrl.get(i)).into(imageViews.get(i));
        }
    }
```

and in case Image Url can come less than ImageViews which is 5 , to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBondException` , you can `compare` both sizes of `URL` and `Images` and do like this -

```
   if (imgUrl != null) {

    int size = (imgUrl.size==imageViews.size() ? imgUrl.size() :imgUrl.size<imageViews.size() ?imgUrl.size() :imageViews.size();
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                    Picasso.get().load(imgUrl.get(i)).into(imageViews.get(i));
                }
            }
```

Or if you want to create these images dynamically and then inflate into your view then you can do all this in for loop.

Comment: What if the imageUrl.size() only have 4? It cause IndexOutOfBoundsException .

Comment: make sure u keep this -> it should be imgUrl.get(i) not imgUrl.get(0) in @salman answer its wrong , i commented there too.

Comment: This is just a copy of my answer, copying other people's answer is not professional

Comment: i dont have to buddy, seriously , can you check when i answered this and timing of your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put your imageviews at an array like below:

```
private List<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();
```

then loop through it and load images:

```
if(imgUrl!= null){  // size : 5
        for(int i= 0; i<imgUrl.size(); i ++){ //loop 
            Picasso.with(this).load(imgUrl.get(i)).into(imageViews.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: it should be imgUrl.get(i) not imgUrl.get(0)

Comment: because get(0), the all of the image view will be same image

Comment: @salman Thank you for your helping but I wanted is the different imageview

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private List<String>imgUrl= new ArrayList<>();
private ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3,imageview4,imageview5;
Private View view;

if(imgUrl!= null){  // size : 5
    for(int i= 0; i<imgUrl.size(); i ++){ //loop 
        if(i==0){
           view=imageview1;
         }
        else if(i==1){
           view=imageview2;
         }
        Picasso.get().load(imgUrl.get(i).into(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this but it not efficient